# refresh page after form download submit

Tags: html, forms, download, refresh, submit

I have a form that as an action returns a download. The problem is that the page will pop-out the download, and you can save it, but it will not allow another form submit.

i was thinking of doing a page refresh after the submit. But i cant figure out how to do that and not stop the download. Do you have any ideas.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seams to be a [bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=30907) in Chrome.
The solution i got from [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=30907#c12) was to open a window before submit and put the target of the form in that window.

```
    function submitForm() {
//next line is the FIX
      window.open('','google');
      form = document.getElementById('myform');
      form.action = "http://www.google.com/search";
      form.target = 'google';
      form.submit();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the initial form POST to an action which returns the same view along with some javascript that triggers the download. Also provide a "Your download should start shortly. Otherwise, click here"-link.

Have a look at

[Auto start file download after form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509116/auto-start-file-download-after-form-submission)

Comment: i would prefer to keep the user in the same page, since he enters some information in the form. Its basicly a report download page and its easier for him to generate multiple reports if he remains in the same page