# Struts2 execute multiple results off of one action from the struts.xml file

Tags: java, xml, jsp, struts2

I want to run two action results from the struts.xml file off of one click from a submit button on a form. Is this possible, and if so how? I have a short example below:

After hitting my submit button on my form is there anyway in struts2 to run both action result **success_csv** and reload the page with result **success**

I have a form on my **index.jsp** such as:

```
<form id="example" name="example" action="makecsv" >
<!-- form sutff --> 
<input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" >
</form>
```

In my **strut.xml** file I have this action:

```
<action name="makecsv" class="com.example.actions.MakecsvAction">

<result name="success_csv" type="stream">

            <param name="contentType">image/jpeg</param>
            <param name="inputName">fileStream</param>
            <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="${filename}"</param>
            <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>

</result>
<result name="success"> index.jsp </result>
</action>
```

Action result success_csv will stream out a file that the user can save or open. Action result success will open index.jsp.

Also my action file **MackcsvAction.java**:

```
public class RegisterAction extends ActionSupport   
{
public String execute() throws Exception 
{
     //blahblah code that creates csv file 
     //sets the filename and fileStream of the file

     return "succes_csv";
}
}
```

Right now it only gives the csv file I would like it also to open index.jsp

Comment: No, you cannot commit two responses to a single HTTP request. The solution that gnanz provided may work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Before thinking about Struts2, ask yourself what do you want to happen from a higher level, from the browser point of view - recall that a browser sents a request, and it expects just a response (a html page OR som other content).

If you want the behaviour in which the request returns a html result page and then (automagically) a download starts, read about [that kind of pattern.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509116/auto-start-file-download-after-form-submission)  (Note, BTW, that there are always two requests.)

Only after this step, when you have decided what you want to happen, think about how you are going to make it happen - i.e. think how you'll implement that with Struts.

For example, I'd say that your "first" action generates the file to be later downloaded,  saves it in a temporary location (together with some secure id), and returns the html pages as result. That page includes a reference to a new request (via a meta refresh, javascript, iframe , or whatever - and probably also an explicit link with the typical 'If your download does not start in a few seconds, click here'), with the id of hte file as parameter.
This request hits a second action, that receives a file id, and returns it as a binary result.

Answer (score 0):

Use listentopics and notifyTopic in Jsp

Visit the following link for listentopics and notifyTopic syntax

http://struts.apache.org/2.0.11/docs/struts-2-spring-2-jpa-ajax.html

add listentopic to form say "filecomplete" on Download file link write notifytopic "triggerFilecomplete" this will trigger the form submission.

Answer (score 0):

You just can't stream an image and at the same time show HTML page.

One solution i could figure out is using javascript to open the image in a new window.