# Android Webview download file when submit post form

Tags: android, forms, file, webclient

I have a webview in my app that is working fine, i can navigate and submit normal forms, click on href, etc. I have one issue with forms that go to a php file that i use to download file.

The code of the php is:

```
$indice=$_POST['indice'];
$sql_file="SELECT * FROM files WHERE indice=".$indice;
$file=$connect->query($sql_file);
$row=$file->fetch_assoc();
header("Content-Type: {$row['type']}\n");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$row['name']}\"\n");
header("Content-Length: {$row['size']}\n");
echo base64_decode($row['data']);
```

I try to manage the download with the function:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)
```

But is not working because is a submit of a form show this function is not executed, it only execute when you click in a href or similar.

With the function "onPageStarted" i can get the url so i know if i submitted the download form but i cant see the post data.

How can i manage the download? In IOS the webclient did automatically and even load the PDF in the webclient.

Best Regards.

Comment: with [downloadmanager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) you can manage file downlaod

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download File inside WebView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069050/download-file-inside-webview)

Comment: I try with a download listener but didnt execute. I debug with a Log.d and never show. So i cant handle with a download listener and dont know why

Comment: Hi, did you ever solve this? I'm battling with it, nearly solved the issue but wondering if you found a simpler way.

Answer (score -2):

You just need your php file to download the file when submitting and add download listener to `Webview` in your application.

*Anyway your post is a possible duplicate of the following:*

[`1. Autostart file download after form submission`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509116/auto-start-file-download-after-form-submission)

[`2. Download File inside WebView`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069050/download-file-inside-webview)

Comment: The form works, i try in the chrome client outside my app and works and the document is downloaded so i dont think the problem is in the form or the post submit.

Comment: Did you add the permission to write in storage so webview can save the downloaded file in storage?

Comment: Yes,<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />